# recursive function that print all options with if statement

Tags: python, recursion

I want my function print all the options, like this:

```
year: 2017 month: 1
year: 2017 month: 2
year: 2017 month: 3
year: 2018 month: 1
year: 2018 month: 2
year: 2018 month: 3
```

I wrote this code:

```
years = [2017, 2018]
years_index = 0
month = 1
def parse():
    global years
    global years_index
    global month
    print(str('year: ' + str(years[years_index])) + ' month: ' + str(month))   
    if years_index < len(years) -1:
        if month < 3:
            month +=1
            parse()
        else:
            years_index +=1
            month = 1
            parse()      
parse()
```

My code print this:

```
year: 2017 month: 1
year: 2017 month: 2
year: 2017 month: 3
year: 2018 month: 1
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use recursion for this. It seems like a job for a simple loop. And you should be able to do it without the need for globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for recursion here:

```
from itertools import product


years = [2017, 2018]
months = [1, 2, 3]

for year, month in product(years, months):
    print(f'year: {year} month: {month}')
```

Because Python lacks tail-recursion optimization and calling a user-defined function is relatively expensive, recursion should only be used when it is *substantially* clearer than a loop.

Comment: Thank you for answer!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
years = [2017, 2018]
years_index = 0
month = 1
def parse():
    global years
    global years_index
    global month
    print(str('year: ' + str(years[years_index])) + ' month: ' + str(month))
    if month < 3:
        month +=1
        parse()
    else:
        years_index +=1
        month = 1
        if years_index >= len(years):
            return

        parse()
parse()
```

I would suggest you to refactor this code and use cycles instead of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to have a little bit of fun doing some OOP on the recursive function. 
Here is how I solved it, hope you can find it useful. Basically solving it required to add an **less than or equal** in the first conditional, and when it finished, in order to avoid the IndexError, I used a catch, since it is part of the intended behaviour.

```
class Example(object):


    #Define variables on an object level
    def __init__(self):
        self.years = [2017, 2018]
        self.years_index = 0
        self.month = 1

    def parse(self):
        try:
            print(str('year: ' + str(self.years[self.years_index])) + ' month: ' + str(self.month))   
            #Had to add an equal sign to make it work on the next year, otherwise it would stop here.
            if self.years_index <= len(self.years) -1:
                if self.month < 3:
                    self.month +=1
                else:
                    self.years_index +=1
                    self.month = 1
                self.parse()      
            pass
        #The catch block is used when the index gets higher than the list's length. So that it does not
        #cause an error, because it is the intended behavior for me. 
        except Exception as e:
            print('Ran out of years');


#Calling function
example = Example()
example.parse()
```